# When I hold on a text in android , a pop up menu comes up. What is it called?

Tags: android, menu

I am new to android development. I want to know what is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk38t.png) called and how do I implement this on my app ?? Some tutorial links will be really helpful. :)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-text-selection

Comment: Thank you very much ! So is this only applicable on marshmallow devices ?